# RxAndroid: Create an observable which make a request and returns success/error based on response

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android

I would like to create an Observable based on the following scenario:

1. A request is made to the server
2. The response then added to cache.
3. If adding to cache is successfully only then is the success response emitted to the observer.

Thanks.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it work this way -

```
makeServerRequest()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.map(someResponse -> {
     if(saveTocache()) {
         return someResponse;
     } else {
         throw new RuntimeException("Error while saving to cache");
     }
})
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.io())
.subscribeWith(new Observer<SomeResponse> (){
    public void onError(Throwable error) {
        // here you will receive the runtime exception you throw.
    }
    :
    :
    :
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can write your method 'saveToCache' with following logic:

```
if (success) return response;
else return new EmptyResponse();
```

then your RxJava code can be like

```
Observable.fromCallable(yourNetworkCall())
.map(response -> saveToCache(response))
.filter(result -> !result.isEmpty())
.subscribe(yourObserver)
```

Comment: but i would like to send an error in case there is an error. would filter() not send the item?

Comment: yes, the filter is just for your third requirement (only emit the response when save to cache success). You can return the error and remove the filter to fit your situation.

Comment: how would you return an error. could you please give an example with code

Comment: you can throws the exception in your method `saveToCache` then handle the exception in `onError` of your observer.